# _T("x") not acting as it should

Tags: c++, windows, char

I am running into lots of problems with Unicode at the moment. As I understand it, TCHAR is defined to be either a wchar_t or a char depending on whether _UNICODE is defined somewhere, and there are various other functions to help with this. Apparently _T("x") should evaulate 'x' to either a wchar_t or a char depending on how stuff is set up. I have the following code:

```
TCHAR desiredClassName = _T("ChatClass");
```

and it is giving me the following unfriendly error message:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const wchar_t [10]' to 'TCHAR'
```

This doesn't really make any sense to me. Surely TCHAR should be a wchar_t thing here? Why is it not?

Incidentally I don't really care about working with Unicode at all, but apparently windows.h or something similar is forcing me to. If there is some handy FAQ somewhere on the internet that explains all these various different types of char arrays and Strings in their various different formats in a way that a newbie could understand, it would be appreciated.

Comment: A TCHAR can be a native wchar_t or a unsigned short, depending on _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED. (If _NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED, TCHAR == wchar_t.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should be a `TCHAR*`, not a `TCHAR`.

Comment: Oh dear, that works. You can see quite easily that I learnt to code in Java, I suppose. THanks.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
TCHAR* desiredClassName = _T("ChatClass");
```

Note the *

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

`TCHAR* desiredClassName = _T("ChatClass");`